# Почему нужно присваивать переменные к другим переменным? Python

Tags: python, переменные

[image: Python переменные]

У меня вопрос, почему нельзя работать с оригинальными переменными, например здесь у нас есть переменная educational_grant, но почему эту переменную присвоили к student_income? Или же у нас есть переменная expenses, почему его присвоили к month_expenses, **почему нельзя работать с оригинальными переменными, а не присваивать их к другим переменным**????

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Код в вопросе должен быть в текстовом виде, а не фотографией.

Comment: Увы, когда открыл вопрос в темной теме сайта, внезапно ослеп от прикрепленного изображения с белым фоном. Вот еще причина, почему текстовую информацию стоит прикреплять в виде текста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь это делается не из соображений "нельзя работать", а из логики задачи: `students_income` -- поступления денег студенту, `educational_grant` -- стипендия; первое, по логике, складывается из второго. Будь у студента еще доходы, например родители прислали еще 15000, то была бы условная переменная `sent_by_parents` , а доходы студента были бы:

```
students_income = edicational_grant + sent_by_parents
```

Примерно та же история с `month_expenses`

А так никто вам не запрещает работать с оригинальными переменными, на то они и переменные